# Python setuptools package_data - pip fails on subfolders

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I am trying to make my own pip package installation to work and I have troubles with subfolders in additional data specified in package_data. Everything seems to be fine (all data are included in produced .zip file), but when I run "pip install myapp", it says: "error: can't copy 'myapp\web\styles': doesn't exist or not a regular file"

Dirtree:

```
projectDir
  setup.py
  myapp
    __init__.py
    webapp.py
    web
      index.html
      styles
        style.css
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
    setup (
        zip_safe = False,
        name = "myapp",
        version = "0.1",
        packages = ["myapp"],
        include_package_data = True,
        package_data = {
            "myapp": ["web/*", "web/styles/*"]
        }
    )
```

Command to create package:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Command to install:

```
pip install myapp-0.1.zip
```

I have even try to specify MANIFEST.in (with no success):

```
include myapp/web/*.*
include myapp/web/styles/*.*
```

When I specify only MANIFEST.in withou package_data, installation success, but there are no files in site-packages/myapp/web so no package_data were copied.

I am quite desperate because I haven't found any suggestion what I am doing wrong and I have spent long time to make it work.

Thaks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have a solution: I have used only MANIFEST.in and removed package_data from setup.py and everything works fine. I thought I have tried this before, but I was wrong.