# Setuptools: Include subdirectories in package_data

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I believe this question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859550/python-setuptools-package-data-pip-fails-on-subfolders) but I'm still a little stuck. I'm trying to install a Python package that has some data files with subdirectories. Here's my setup:

```
setup.py
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py
        module.py
        data/
            tables.dat
            spoons.dat
            sub/
                forks.dat
```

Following [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/dist/node11.html) I tried to add:

```
setup(...,
  packages=['mypkg'],
  package_dir={'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
  package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.dat', 'data/sub/*.dat']},
)
```

I install the module with `python setup.py install` (though eventually I'll use `python setup.py sdist upload` to upload the package to pypi so others can `pip install` the module.

After running the `python setup.py install` command, to find the module location, I then `import mypkg` and `print(mypkg.__file__)`. In the package directory, however, I can see `data` but not `data/sub`. Does anyone know what I'm missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce as the `package_data` spec is perfectly fine - getting the files included on `install`, `sdist`, `bdist_wheel` as well as verious `pip install`s. Maybe some cached stuff?

Comment: Curious. I may not be attempting to fetch the package files correctly--given the setup above, how should I fetch the files in data/sub/*.dat @hoefling

Comment: Ah you're quite right @hoefling, thanks for your note!

Comment: Nice, not sure if I helped, but happy to hear the issue is solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it turns out the above works fine!

To install the module to my `site-packages/mypkg` location, I just had to use: `python setup.py sdist` and then `pip install dist/mypkg-0.0.1.tar.gz`.

Then my data files were in `site-packages/mypkg`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, in my case the problem was the package was installed and when executing

```
pip install .
```

in my local it didn't reinstall, so the packages weren't included.

Uninstall before install was the key for me